# Problem with matrices using \linespread

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to set matrices like this

[image: Figure 1]

but if I add \linespread{1.5} into my code seems like that

[image: Figure 2]

How can I change my code to the style in Figure 1 without removing the command \ linespread {1.5}?

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \linespread{1.5}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            1 & 2 & 3\\
            2 & 2 & 3\\
            2 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You need to change spacing in display math environments, For example `\[\linespread{1}\selectfont
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    2 & 2 & 3\\
    2 & 2 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}
    \]`.

Comment: Thanks Zarko! It worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, if the following solution gives what you after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}    % <---   
\everydisplay{\linespread{1}\selectfont} % <---

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2] $x^2$ \lipsum[1][3]
    \[
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    2 & 2 & 3\\
    2 & 2 & 3\\
\end{bmatrix}
    \]
\lipsum[1][4-6]
\begin{align}
a = b   \\
c = d
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Zarko!